# What's the difference between these functions in golang?

Tags: go

I'm new to Go programming and wondering what's the  difference (if any) there between

a.

```
func DoSomething(a *A) {        
      b = a
}
```

b.

```
func DoSomething(a A) {     
    b = &a
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually asking what the difference of those `b`'s are, one is a pointer to the object passed as an argument to `DoSomething`, and the other is a pointer to a copy of the object passed as an argument to `DoSomething`.

https://play.golang.org/p/ush0hDZsdE

```
type A struct {
    f string
}

func DoSomethingPtr(a *A) {
    b := a
    b.f = "hi"
}

func DoSomething(a A) {
    b := &a
    b.f = "hey"
}

func main() {
    x := A{"hello"}
    DoSomething(x)
    fmt.Println(x)
    DoSomethingPtr(&x)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Comment: I know that. Just wondering do they assign different values to `b`?

Comment: Both are pointers to a struct of type `A` if that's what you are asking. They have the same type, but are not pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, these two functions will assign different values to `b`.  The second one makes a copy of the argument, and so the `a` inside the function generally has a different memory address than whatever input is passed into the function.  See [this playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/9gaCHa7K74)

```
package main

type A struct{
    x int
}
var b *A

func d(a *A) {
    b = a
}

func e(a A) {
    b = &a
}

func main() {
    var a = A{3}
    println(&a)
    d(&a)
    println(b)
    e(a)
    println(b)
}
```

Interestingly, if you make the type `A` an empty struct instead, and initialize `var a = A{}`, you actually see the *same* value for `b` in the `println` statements.

That's because for the empty-struct type, there can only really only ever be 1 value, and its immutable, so all instances of it share the same memory address?

Comment: Your last paragraph is correct; an empty struct is immutable, so there's no reason to make another copy of it. This is why we use `chan struct{}` for signaling when we don't need to send a value.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `b` would be assigned a different value in each function.  The values are different because one is passing a copied value and the other is passing a pointer to the original value in memory.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A string

func DoSomethingPtr(a *A) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func DoSomething(a A) {
    fmt.Println(&a)
}

func main() {
    x := A("hello")
    DoSomething(x)
    DoSomethingPtr(&x)
}
```

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/IDxnTaj-Hm) is the executable proof.